# Adding sub-project in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, subproject

I have 2 projects in a `workspaces`, both are built using `Swift`.

I want to use one of the project as a sub-project of the other one and the classes, which are in the sub-project, in the parent project.
My sub-project is using `bridging-header`.

I have tried to add one project as a reference to another and imported the class, which is in sub-project, but it didn't work.

> Showing me Error: "No such module "

Please help me achieving this?

Comment: Did you add these classes to public classes?

Comment: Yes. I have made these classes public, but the project is unable to import sub-project framework, which is having bridging-header.

Comment: Did you set your bridging-header in your target's Build Settings?

Comment: That it is set in the framework project. The framework project is compiling properly, but when i am inducing the framework in my other project, it is throwing error. It says two errors: (1) "Framework name" file not found. When i am trying to import it. and (2) Failed to import bridging header.

Comment: Did you add .framework file to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"?

Comment: Yes, it is added in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" and in "Embedded Binaries".

Comment: I think you shouldn't directly import your subproject's classes. You should create a public header and add your public classes to there. Then, you should just import this public header when you want to use.

Comment: Thanx for your effort @CandostDagdeviren. Made it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, thing i did was:

1. Removed bridging header file, which was bridging my objective-C and
   swift code from my framework and deleted the bridging header file from Build Settings.
2. Created a file named "Framework-name.h" and copied all the header files, which were there in my bridging header file, into "Framework-name.h" file.
3. import "Framework-name.h" inside "Framework-name.h" file (this is vey important, it will keep the file at the root level of the framework).
4. Made "Framework-name.h" and files that were included in Framework-name.h" file public.
5. Created an aggregate target for my framework. https://medium.com/@syshen/create-an-ios-universal-framework-148eb130a46c
6. Built the framework.
7. Drag and drop the created framework into the root level of another sample project.
8. Test the framework, writing **import Framework-name** in swift class of the sample project.
9. Build the project.
10. Bingo!!!